# MySQL terminology "constraints" vs "foreign keys" difference?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

I'm looking at [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and trying to sort out the distinction between FOREIGN KEYs and CONSTRAINTs. I thought an FK **was** a constraint, but the docs seem to talk about them like they're separate things.

The syntax for creating an FK is (in part)

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
```

So the "CONSTRAINT" clause is optional.

Why would you include it or not include it?

If you leave it out does MySQL create a foreign key but not a constraint?

Or is it more like a "CONSTRAINT" is nothing more than a name for you FK, so if you don't specify it you get an anonymous FK?

What is the difference?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, a foreign key is a type of constraint.  MySQL has uneven support for constraints:

- `PRIMARY KEY`: yes as table constraint and column constraint.
- `FOREIGN KEY`: yes as table constraint, but only with InnoDB and BDB storage engines; otherwise parsed but ignored.
- `CHECK`: supported as table constraint and column constraint in MySQL 8.0.16 and later; parsed but ignored in earlier versions.
- `UNIQUE`: yes as table constraint and column constraint.
- `NOT NULL`: yes as column constraint.
- `DEFERRABLE` and other constraint attributes: no support.

The `CONSTRAINT` clause allows you to name the constraint explicitly, either to make metadata more readable or else to use the name when you want to drop the constraint.  The SQL standard requires that the `CONSTRAINT` clause is optional.  If you leave it out, the RDBMS creates a name automatically, and the name is up to the implementation.

Answer (score 11):

In general (not necessary MySQL), foreign keys are constraints, but constraints are not always foreign keys. Think of primary key constraints, unique constraints etc.

Coming back to the specific question, you are correct, omitting CONSTRAINT [symbol] part will create a FK with an auto-generated name.

Answer (score 4):

CREATE TABLE DDLs are of this format - notice the UNIQUE KEY and FOREIGN KEY definition syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE my_dbschema.my_table (
    id INT unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    account_nbr INT NOT NULL,
    account_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    active_flg CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    vendor_nbr INT NOT NULL,
    create_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    create_usr_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DFLTUSR',
    last_upd_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE current_timestamp,
    last_upd_usr_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DFLTUSR',
    UNIQUE KEY uk1_my_table(account_nbr, account_name),
    FOREIGN KEY fk1_my_table(vendor_nbr) REFERENCES vendor(vendor_nbr)
    );
```

In this format, MySQL is creating INDEX-es with the names uk1_my_table and fk1_my_table automatically; but the FK object name is something different--my_table_ibfk_1 (ie. tablename_ibfk_N – system defined). So `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk1_my_table` won’t work (and hence frustrating and raising alarms), as there’s no FK db object by that name.

An alternative DDL format for the constraints (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
CREATE TABLE my_dbschema.my_table (
    id INT unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    account_nbr INT NOT NULL,
    account_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    active_flg CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    vendor_nbr INT NOT NULL,
    create_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    create_usr_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DFLTUSR',
    last_upd_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE current_timestamp,
    last_upd_usr_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DFLTUSR',
    CONSTRAINT uk1_my_table UNIQUE KEY (account_nbr, account_name),
    CONSTRAINT fk1_my_table FOREIGN KEY (vendor_nbr) REFERENCES vendor(vendor_nbr)
    );
```

In this format, MySQL is still creating INDEX-es with the names uk1_my_table and fk1_my_table automatically, but the FK object name is not something different – it’s fk1_my_table as mentioned in the DDL. So `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk1_my_table` works, but leaves behind the namesake INDEX.

`ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX fk1_my_table` won’t work initially (when the FK is not yet dropped), with an error message that it is being used in a FK! If the DROP FK command has been executed successfully, only then the DROP INDEX works.

Comment: A great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer for MySQL but FK's are constraints. Anything that forces your data into a certain condition is a constraint. There are several kinds of constraints, Unique, Primary Key, Check and Foreign Keys are all constraints. Maybe MySQL has others.

Sometimes words are allowed in commands but not required sheerly for readability like the FROM in the DELETE statement.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints need indexes, so when you create, for example, a foreign key constraint, MySQL automatically creates an index too.

Answer (score 1):

A Foreign Key and its associated Foreign Key Constraint are not the same thing, in the way a car engine and a crank-shaft are not the same thing.  The engine converts gasoline explosions into straight line motion (the pistons), and the crankshaft converts that straight-line motion into turning motion, which then turns the wheels of the car.  Together, the engine and the crank-shaft make the car go.

Likewise, a Foreign Key and a Foreign Key Constraint are not the same thing, but they work together to create the idea of a "Foreign Key Relationship".

DEFINITIONS:

"Foreign Key" is short for Foreign Key Index.

"Constraint" is short for Foreign Key Constraint.

The Index and the Constraint together make the "Foreign Key Relationship".

The Foreign Key Relationship is the requirement for a value in a child table to exist in its parent table, thus ensuring data integrity in a database.

Because Key means Index, we don't say "Foreign Key Index".  We just say Foreign Key, but not saying "Index" is the cause of much confusion.

Creating a Foreign Key (a Foreign Key Index) creates a Binary Search Tree (also called a dictionary, because the tree is used to look up values).  The Binary Search Tree (BST) then exists in computer memory and takes up physical disk space, but allows for O(log n) JOIN access time (almost instantly) from the child table to the parent table.

Creating a Foreign Key Constraint is creating a rule, which is a piece of code that gets called when you process (INSERT, SELECT, etc...) on the foreign key column.  A constraint is essentially a database trigger.  A constraint is like an email filter: a piece of code that gets called on a certain action, such as WHEN (new email) IF (From: crzy@xgfrnd.com) {SEND TO Trash Folder;}.

Thus, a Foreign Key "Constraint" would be a piece of code that gets called (a trigger, essentially), that looks like such: WHEN INSERT child_column IF (NOT IN parent_table) DO NOT ALLOW INSERT.

And then you have your Cascades and Updates and Delete rules (constraints), wth their various if / then conditions and operations, etc...

So, a "Foreign Key" is a BST dictionary mapping child table column values to parent table column values.  The purpose of the Foreign Key is speed (NOT data integrity, since data integrity can be achieved, albeit slowly, without an index).

A Foreign Key Constraint is a rule: code that gets triggered on SQL statements, and that rule uses the BST as a dictionary for fast processing, to avoid traversing tables, which may eventually create Cartesian-like behavior.  The purpose of the Foreign Key Constraint is data integrity.

I have never created a parent table where the referenced parent column was not itself a key in the parent table.  So the question then is, is the Foreign Key Index (the BST dictionary) actually needed?  The Constraint is definitely needed, to ensure data integrity, but Foreign Key Index (the BST dictionary) is actually not needed to fulfill the Foreign Key rule, thus, "Key" and "Index" have two different definitions.  The "Index" is the BST tree, and the "Key" is the rule (the idea that the child value must exist in the parent table).  In MySQL, however, the Foreign Key Index is needed, only because they programmed it that way, but they didn't have to.  Having a BST tree is just faster, when the parent column is not itself indexed.  I would never recommend making the referenced parent column not a key (index).  But if someone did reference a non-indexed parent column using a Foreign Key Constraint without a BST, then the SQL operations would be progressively slow, and your application may eventually come to a crawl.

THE CONFUSION:  Adjectives and verbs.

When we say "Foreign Key" colloquially, we are usually referring to the Foreign Key Relationship, not the Foreign Key Index.  But the word Key means Index.  So that's the root source of all the confusion.  I.e. lack of reserved keyword definition standards.  In a MySQL CREATE TABLE statement, FOREIGN KEY means the Index (the BST), and CONSTRAINT names the rule, therefore, the confusion is coming from the difference in the phrase "Foreign Key" when we speak, versus "Foreign Key" being defined in an actual SQL statement.

In computer code, "Foreign" is an adjective and "Key" is a noun, meaning the Index.

In colloquial speech, the phrase "Foreign Key" is an adjective, and the words "Index", "Constraint", and "relationship" are all nouns.  When we speak to each other across office cubicles, "Foreign Key" means the "idea" of data integrity (i.e. the rule, not the index).

Unfortunately, programmers are always searching for short-hand ways of typing, which often causes confusion.  Everything in computer science is a trade-off, and that includes coding style.

If the syntax for creating a MySQL table instead used the following reserved words, then the confusion would disappear: FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT `fk1_rule_child_column` FOREIGN KEY INDEX (`fk_bst_child_to_parent_column`) REFERENCES `parent_table` (`parent_column`)

Furthermore, since MySQL always creates both an Index and a Constraint, the MySQL creators could have completely hidden (abstraction) the dual element of the Foreign Key Relationship.  Or, perhaps I should say, they could have bundled them together so the user doesn't have to think about the dual aspect, and instead just creates a "Foreign Key" `my_foreign_key` with the dual details hidden.

Nevertheless, MySQL is inexpensive, robust, and it's great.  For the record, I have zero complaints, and I have only gratitude for the creators.  For my part, they can do as they please.

Incidentally, as a style recommendation, you should ALWAYS name your parent and child columns the same, and your table names should ALWAYS contain their Foreign Key Relationships.  So your tables

`customers`
`products`
`attributes`
`orders`

should instead be named

`customers`
`products`
`product_attributes`
`customer_product_orders`

That way, you and your successors know the foreign key relationships just by reading any table name.  If that's too much typing for you, then

`cust`
`prod`
`prod_attr`
`cust_prod_ord`

I don't know if my BST and Rule explanation is correct.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, when you view a table structure, the CONSTRAINT name (not the FOREIGN KEY name) appears in the Keyname column with BTREE next to it, which implies that either the MySQL folks got the keywords CONSTRAINT and FOREIGN KEY backward, or PHPMyAdmin is pulling the CONSTRAINT name when it should be pulling the FOREIGN KEY name.  I am angling for this being a MySQL mistake, and it's all just been kept mum, and swept under the rug, which would account for much of the confusion.  Can anyone confirm?  Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: MySQL Foreign Keys came later. Per MySQL Workbench & phpMyAdmin's workings, maybe someone originally worked on Foreign Keys in MySQL, & Workbench & phpMyAdmin were anticipating that. Perhaps Foreign Keys were abandoned, & maybe the original MySQL Soft. Engineer didn't quite have it right. Maybe someone else years later finished the implementation, having to use the mistaken terminology of the first guy who got confused & abandoned it. I am guessing, but it looks to be the case, & nobody would ever want to come out & admit Foreign Keys were built off an originally flawed design. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most confusing topìc in MySQL.

Many people say that, for instance, the 'PRIMARY KEY', the 'FOREIGN KEY', and the 'UNIQUE' key are actually indexes! (MySQL official documentation is included here)

Many others, on the other hand, say that they're rather constraints (which does make sense, cause when you use them, you're really imposing restrictions on the affected columns).

If they really are indexes, then what's the point in using the constraint clausule in order to give it a name, since you're supposed to be able to use the name of that index when you created it?

Example:

... FOREIGN KEY index_name (col_name1, col_name2, ...)

If FOREIGN KEY is an index, then we should be able to use the index_name to handle it. However, we can't.

But if they're not indexes but actual contraints which do use indexes to work, then this does make sense.

In any case, we don't know. Actually, nobody seems to know.