# How do I rename a foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

We've just completed a long-running migration on a large table, and ended up with the following constraint on our conversation_tags table:

```
CONSTRAINT `conversation_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`)
```

Unfortunately, there was a bug somewhere, because what we wanted was:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_conversation_tags_tags` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`)
```

Dropping and re-adding the constraint would mean another two long queries.  Is there any way to rename the constraint in a single query?

Comment: InnoDB interprets foreign key constraint names that begin with the string “tbl_name_ibfk_” as internally generated names.  In the future if you need to RENAME TABLE, “tbl_name_ibfk_” will be rename automatically. But fk_conversation_tags_tags won't.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> Multiple **ADD**, **ALTER**, **DROP**, and **CHANGE** clauses are permitted in a
>   single **ALTER TABLE** statement, separated by commas. *This is a MySQL
>   extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per
>   ALTER TABLE statement.*

This way you can combine the drop and recreate into one query, and that should be faster than dropping the constraint and creating it in two queries:

```
ALTER TABLE conversation_tags
DROP FOREIGN KEY `conversation_tags_ibfk_1`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_conversation_tags_tags` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`);
```

Comment: Obviously this is a much more recent answer than the originally accepted one, but it's also a much better answer.

Comment: Is there a way to rename all constraint name with wildcard such as abc_foo_* to abc_bar_* ?

Comment: On the "DROP FOREIGN..." line, use ` instead of '.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sorry, but constraints can only be dropped and re-attacched in mySQL

Answer (score 3):

The feature does not seems to be available in mysql ALTER TABLE syntax.

However it is supported for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer in [MySQL terminology "constraints" vs "foreign keys" difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310561/mysql-terminology-constraints-vs-foreign-keys-difference/34298305#34298305) to understand why the constraint name was different than what you desired. 
However, MySQL doesnot have rename constraint feature and hence need to DROP and ADD FK with desired name . 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html