# MySQL Foreign key definition?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm playing around with mysql and I found two ways to define Foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY name (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT name
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
        REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

What would be the difference between these two? Are they the same and its just a matter of preference how you like to write? Or there are some differences?

Comment: not voting to close but this article may be duplicate with yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310561/mysql-terminology-constraints-vs-foreign-keys-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> The syntax for an InnoDB foreign key constraint definition in the `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement looks like this:
>
> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>     [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>     REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>     [ON DELETE reference_option]
>     [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>     RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
> ```
>
> ***`index_name`*** represents a foreign key ID. If given, this is ignored if an index for the foreign key is defined explicitly. Otherwise, if `InnoDB` creates an index for the foreign key, it uses ***`index_name`*** for the index name.
>
> Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - If the `CONSTRAINT symbol` clause is given, the ***`symbol`*** value must be unique in the database. If the clause is not given, `InnoDB` creates the name automatically.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> If the `FOREIGN KEY` clause included a `CONSTRAINT` name when you created the foreign key, you can refer to that name to drop the foreign key. Otherwise, the ***`fk_symbol`*** value is internally generated by `InnoDB` when the foreign key is created.

Therefore, your first example creates an automatically named foreign key constraint with an index named `name` (if one does not already exist); whereas your second example creates a foreign key constraint named `name` with an automatically generated index name (if one does not already exist).

Other than that, they are identical.

Comment: @Waldermort: It's almost entirely quoted from the manual... :/